# the_author_meta not resetting

Tags: author, user-meta

I'm looping through posts normally. I want to display the author ... simple `<?php the_author(); ?>` gives me "Patrick Daly". Nah, I just want the first name, so I use `<?php the_author_meta( 'first_name' ); ?>` and now I get .... "John"???

So the actual author of the post is "Patrick Daly" -- whose user account has all the correct information in it (nothing about John).

The loop seems to not be clearing "John's" meta and continues to reuse it. It does it's job when using `the_author();` though.

Anything I need to be doing to clear `the_author_meta();`?

Here's what each function outputs on a single post (where the values in the database don't have John Doe):

```
           the_author_meta( 'ID' ); : 1
   the_author_meta( 'first_name' ); : John
    the_author_meta( 'last_name' ); : Doe
 the_author_meta( 'display_name' ); : Patrick Daly
                      the_author(); : Patrick Daly
```

This is a really `if( have_posts() )` query, but I've tried `wp_reset_postdata()` and of course it didn't work.

Comment: Should work... post your actual (not so) working code please.

Comment: Seems odd. Have you tried explicitly declaring the user ID? the_author_meta( $field, $userID );

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins to see if the issue persists?